# Can't install the proprietary Nvidia driver in Additional Drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 22.04

Here I took a 39 second screen recording of the problem https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dybNZ7_j1n4 . I will say this when I was installing 22.04 I decided to check the box that said "look for and install 3rd party software", now I never click that box but this time I decided to, just for your information. So did you follow the youtube link, notice how it says "no proprietary drivers are in use"? Well if I try to click on any of the buttons nothing happens, what I mean is, when I click on the orange button nothing happens, and when I click on the other un-highlighted buttons nothing happens, so when I click on "nvidia-driver-525(proprietary,tested)" nothing happens, seriously when I click on any of those buttons to change the driver nothing happens at all, is this a bug?

I'm getting screen tearing, I had screen tearing on 20.04 but what fixed it was switching to the nvidia proprietary driver. And here it's not letting me do anything. I mean it when I say I can click on all those buttons as much as I want, but nothing happens.

Edit: Can I at least get someone to say "Yes this is normal" or "No this is not normal, this is a bug"?

Edit: So I just simply did a clean install of Ubuntu 22.04 and this time around I chose not to click the box that says "install 3rd party software" and this fixed my problem, I was able to click and install nvidia driver 525 (proprietary,tested). I provided a screenshot below. So yeah before I couldn't click on anything or change the driver, but now I can after doing a clean install and not choosing the box that says install 3rd party software. I had a hunch that that's what was causing the issue.

Notice in the youtube video it says "continue using a manually installed driver", and now it says "using X.Org X server-Nouveau display driver", ya notice that difference?

[image]

Comment: What Ubuntu release and what Nvidia hardware are you running?  Did you turn off secure boot?  Did you enroll any MOK key at installation?  Give us the details and we can make some reasonable suggestions to help.  Sounds like you don't have any Nvidia proprietary driver installed.

Comment: @ubfan1 First off did you see the video I provided? Why can't I click on any of the buttons to change drivers, isn't that a bug? My PC has a GTX 750TI that I bought back in 2015. No MOK keys that I know of so I've no idea what you're talking about there. In 20.04 I was able to to click those buttons and change it to the nvidia proprietary driver. AGAIN, did you watch the video? When I click on those buttons nothing happens, that's a bug right, cause I was able to click those buttons just fine in 20.04.

Comment: @Nmath I made a new edit to the post please take a look, I solved the problem. "It's not recommended to manually install the Nvidia driver" Why do you say that? I have a GTX 750TI and I'm pretty sure the "nvidia driver 525 (proprietary,tested)" is the one I'm supposed to be using.

Comment: @ubfan1 Hello. I made a new update to the post please take a look, I solved the problem.

Comment: You can answer your own question, and at some point accept it, helping others and gaining some rep points.

Comment: @ubfan1 I'm a newbie how do I do that?

Comment: Scroll to the bottom of your question page and fill in the answer section, then click on the post button. I'm not sure what the "accept" conditions are, maybe after a few days and/or after an up-vote.

Answer (score 0):

You can install these drivers manually. Anyway, I've recently upgraded to 22.04 and during the upgrade you get a warning message informing that some 3rd party libraries will be disabled. You must activate them by configuring the /etc/apt/sources.list and other source files located in this folder.

Comment: Listen I'm a newbie here so what do I need to do exactly? Did you watch the video, why can't I click on any of those buttons? In 20.04 I was easily able to click those buttons and change drivers.

Comment: "You must activate them by configuring the /etc/apt/sources.list and other source files located in this folder." How? I'm sorry but I'm a total novice here.

Comment: Hello. I made a new update to the post please take a look, I solved the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your replies. You must edit and comment, uncomment or add the lines of the third party repos.

Answer (score 0):

First, welcome to Ask Ubuntu, and to Ubuntu in general. A lot of times you'll receive or find answers out there that you won't understand. That's okay! A ton of stuff is already documented, so if you see something you don't understand, just copy the relevant terms and search for an explanation. I'll try to offer some of that.

From what I can tell, what your screen shows is that you are already using a manually installed driver for the relevant hardware. As for what Raul said before that you were asking about—you need to check that the source repositories activated. You can do that with the gui (graphical user interface) you are already showing us in the video. Click the tab that says other software, and scroll down the list of repositories to see if any don't have the box marked on that you need on. Since you're also seem to be okay with proprietary software, you want to make sure that you have enabled the option to use that. To do that, click on the Ubuntu Software tab in the same window and tick next to "Proprietary drivers for devices." If that wasn't already ticked, that might actually allow you to access the drives that were greyed out in your video.

Comment: Hello. I made a new update to the post please take a look, I solved the problem.

Comment: So I've just done a clean install of 22.04 and I'm just now checking other software and it's empty, and "Proprietary drivers for devices." was already checked.

Comment: That's great glad it looks like you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved by reinstalling Ubuntu, not selecting the *Install 3rd party software* option and then manually installing the NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-525 (proprietary,tested) from Software & Updates -> *Additional Drivers* tab as shown in the below screenshot.

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

The screenshot in your question doesn't look right to me because Ubuntu is still using the open source Nouveau graphics drivers instead of the proprietary Nvidia graphics drivers. To install the proprietary Nvidia graphics drivers you must first unintall the existing proprietary Nvidia graphics drivers as follows.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get remove '^nvidia'
sudo apt autoremove 
sudo reboot
```

An easy way of automatically selecting and installing the Nvidia proprietary graphics driver that is compatible with your computer is to run the following commands in the terminal:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install
sudo reboot
```

The `install` option of `ubuntu-drivers` automatically installs drivers that are appropriate for automatic installation including their dependencies without any unnecessary guesswork.